# Difference between @ResponseBody\npublic ReturnType .. and public @ResponseBody ReturnType?

Tags: java, json, spring, jakarta-ee

Is there a difference between

```
@ResponseBody
public Object method(etc..) {
    etc..
}
```

and

```
public @ResponseBody Object method(etc..){
    etc..
}
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between them.

If the method is annotated with @ResponseBody, the return type is written to the response HTTP body. The return value will be converted to the declared method argument type using HttpMessageConverters

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody